# add key value pair to existing array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an the variable `$users` set to an array that resembles the below

```
Array(
    [4] => Array(
        [userid] => 4
        [name] => Mike
        [gender] => M
    )

    [5] => Array(
        [userid] => 5
        [name] => Sally
        [gender] => F
    )

    [6] => Array(
        [userid] => 6
        [name] => Steve
        [gender] => M
    )
)
```

I then have code that loops through this array to call a function to calculate age.

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $age = getUserAge($user->id);
}
```

How do I take the variable `$age` and add it into `$users` to result with the follow array?

```
Array(
    [4] => Array(
        [userid] => 4
        [name] => Mike
        [gender] => M
        [age] => 35
    )

    [5] => Array(
        [userid] => 5
        [name] => Sally
        [gender] => F
        [age] => 24
    )

    [6] => Array(
        [userid] => 6
        [name] => Steve
        [gender] => M
        [age] => 32
    )
)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
foreach($users as &$user){
    $age = getUserAge($user['userid']);
    $user['age'] = $age;
}
```

*Compact Version:*

```
foreach($users as &$user){
    $user['age'] = getUserAge($user['userid']);
}
```

Note the ampersand before the array variable name meaning the variable is passed by reference, and so can be modified. See the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) for more info.

Comment: Use `$user["userid"]` since its an array not an object

Answer (score 11):

```
foreach($users as $index => $user) {
    $users[$index]['age'] = getUserAge($user['userid']);
}
```

Comment: This method worked for me where the above didn't, since the &$ was messing with other aspects.